# use sharepoint online content viewing data in power bi

Tags: content, powerbi, reporting

My business is requesting an adoption report. Simply put they need to know how many times our external customers are viewing the contents of the libraries. I know on site level there's a content viewing report but I'm looking for a way to automatically report this in power BI if possible.

Comment:  what  have  you  triieeedd???!!!!

Comment: Can you define "external"? Are the users using anonymous links? Federated AD accounts? Sharing links?